# Unable set current navigation of web

Tags: 2013, navigation

I want to change the current navigation to "Structural Navigation: Display only the navigation items below the current site" of sub site. I got [this](http://discoveringsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/19/programmatically-set-navigation-settings-in-sharepoint-2013/) which shows how to set the current navigation and based on that I developed code as below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using(SPSite site= new SPSite("http://............"))
    {
        string val = null;
        Console.WriteLine(site.Url);

        SPWeb web = site.AllWebs["Depts"];
        if (web != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(web.Url);
            PublishingWeb my = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
            WebNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);
            navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.Unknown;
            my.Navigation.CurrentIncludePages = false;
            my.Navigation.CurrentIncludeSubSites = false;
            navigationSettings.Update();
            my.Update();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Completed..");
        Console.ReadKey();
        web.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But when I run the code I am getting the error at line:`navigationSettings.CurrentNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.Unknown;` that indicates "The value "Unknown" is not allowed for property type "StandardNavigationSource"."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

that is strange! when your writing your code and you enter `StandardNavigationSource` and then add  **. (decimal)** does it come out with a list of options? also i know more than likely you have but have you add the following references withinn the project and top of class?

```
web.Navigation (Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint)
publishingWeb.Navigation (Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing)
WebNavigationSettings (Namespace: Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation)
```

also are you sure its ment to be that? and not:

```
        PublishingWeb my = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
        WebNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new WebNavigationSettings(web);
        navigationSettings.GlobalNavigation.Source = StandardNavigationSource.Unknown;
```

> There are two navigations. The Global navigation (also called Top
>   navigation) and the Current navigation (also called left navigation or
>   quicklaunch). Both of these can be set to different to use different
>   sources. They can inherit from their parent (if a subsite only), use
>   managed navigation, or structural navigation. All you need to do is
>   select the webNavigationSettings object, choose which navigation to
>   set, and select a source for that navigation.

so it is the quick launch that your trying to ammend ;), i know that you probably are, im just making sure!

more importantly I would also like to note from msdn on the error your getting:

> This property determines whether the switchable site map provider will
>   use the taxonomy site map provider or the portal site map provider in
>   the standard configurations. **If the settings are in an advanced
>   configuration**, then this property returns
>   StandardNavigationSource.Unknown (section 3.1.5.11.1.1). If the
>   protocol client attempts to assign the
>   StandardNavigationSource.Unknown value to this property, **the protocol
>   server MUST return an InvalidOperationException error.**

going to section [3.1.5.10.1.1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh163927(v=office.12).aspx) will show:

> Indicates that the navigation scheme is in an advanced configuration
>   that does not correspond to one of the standard configurations.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, I added all the assemblies and also the intelligent box shows the option of selecting `unknown`. But when I run the program I get the error.